# GIT: Holding pushes for approval?

Tags: git

Say I setup a repository. I want some users to be able to push, and some I'd like to go over the content of the push before approving it. Is there a concept such as conditional pushing? a queue for approval pending pushes?

Comment: Is this an open source project or closed source? Github has [pull requests](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/) but I don't think it exists elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case most people would prefer the pull model. The user sets up (or has someone else set up) a repo that's visible to you, and they push all the changes they want to it. Then you act as a gatekeeper of sorts and pull only the commits that you deem "worthy".

Github is set up around this model. You can fork other people's projects, make your modifications, and then send a "pull request" basically asking the maintainer to please merge your changes.

Answer (score 6):

You essentially want a code review tool. There are a few out there for git but probably the best one is [Gerrit](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/).

See my notes on installing it on a CentOs box here:
http://readystate4.com/2011/06/23/notes-on-setting-up-gerrit-code-review-on-centos/

If you don't want to go through the complexity of setting up your own code review system, you can use Github and it's feature of sending pull-requests to each other, which need to be approved before the code is merged into the code base.

If you want to go even more simpler and stay with your own git setup, accept only branches from other devs, check them out, and merge them in if they look good. There's no way with plain git to only accept pushes to certain branches. You can use tools like [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) for these kind of access controls.